# memory leaks with arc in init method

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

Why is the Leaks Instrument telling me this is a leak?  I am using ARC.
And how should I do this so that it doesn't leak?
BTW, I tried changing 'strong' to 'weak' but then got a warning `"Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment"`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //<== leak here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `myArray` is leaking? It could also be its owner that's leaking (`self`).

Comment: yes, i tried it with _myArray instead, and still get the leak (i updated the code above to show that example)

Comment: @Harris: The line of code you're pointing to isn't leaking. Either the object that has this property is being leaked, or you're passing the array off to some other code that retains and leaks it. Try turning on the object allocation instrument, it can track all the retains/releases that happened to this particular array and you can use that to find out where it's unbalanced.

Comment: That isn't a leak, with ARC the release is autogenerated in the autogenerated dealloc method.  Perhaps something else is retaining that array so it isn't getting deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ARC is actually turned on? Try adding something like [self release] just to see if it compiles. If it does, ARC isn't on.

Comment: Yes, i have verified that ARC is turned on.

Comment: That kind of sounds like a static analyzer bug then. Nothing about that should be a leak. Have you checked with Instruments to see if it actually leaks?

Comment: @Catfish_Man: He is using the leaks instrument already, not the static analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access `properties` via their `getter` within either `init` or `dealloc` methods. Instead, you should set the backing ivar directly, like this:

```
-(id)init
{  
  self = [super init]; 

  if (self)
  {  
    _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //<== leak here
  } 

  return self;  
}
```

Note: if you're using the `auto-synthesize` feature in the latest version of Xcode -- that is, you're not manually writing an `@synthesize` line -- the backing ivar will be named the same as your property with an underscore in front of it.

Try this above, and see if the leak goes away.

Good luck.

Comment: I agree with your general advice, but making this change will have zero effect upon the memory semantics of the code.